# How to fix Oracle Error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" with 'AS' keyword using several tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

Oracle gives an error for the following code:

```
SELECT actor_name, 
       char_name
  FROM zActor AS zAct, 
       zCharacter AS zChar
 WHERE zChar.char_num IN
       (SELECT COUNT(zP.char_num) AS charCount
          FROM zPlay AS zP, 
               zActor AS zAct, 
               zCharacter AS zChar
         WHERE zAct.actor_num = zP.actor_num
           AND zChar.char_num = zP.char_num
      GROUP BY zAct.actor_name
  HAVING COUNT(zP.char_num) > 1);
```

I cannot figure out why because I am somewhat new to oracle but have a good grasp on SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should learn how to use modern join syntax.  Your query is hard to follow.

Comment: we are not allowed to so i have to steer away from using it. thanks.

Comment: that worked, but now i'm discovering my query, as a whole, might be incorrect, because the output is blank, which is incorrect.

Comment: In that case, please update your question with posting your expected result and what is the exact result. Or Post a new question. It will be better if you post a new question

Comment: @motto, I have updated my comment as an answer, If you find useful, please upvote it.

Comment: being that im new to stackoverflow, and that i cant post another question for 90 more minutes, is it frowned upon to erase my original question and replace it with a new one? is that even possible?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106249/update-a-question-or-post-a-new-question It may help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your subquery and outer query are using the same alias name zAct and aChar. Just change the names, it should work

Comment: After using the following code: 'SELECT actor_name, char_name
FROM zActor AS zAct, zCharacter AS zChar
WHERE zChar.char_num IN
(SELECT COUNT(zP.char_num) AS charCount
FROM zPlay AS zP, zActor AS zA, zCharacter AS zC
WHERE zA.actor_num = zP.actor_num
AND zC.char_num = zP.char_num
GROUP BY zA.actor_name
HAVING COUNT(zP.char_num) > 1);' I still received the same error message.

Comment: can you share the columns in both the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing As in table alias. Give zActor zAct instead of zActor AS zAct. Do this with all the table alias.

```
 SELECT actor_name, 
        char_name
  FROM zActor  zAct, 
       zCharacter  zChar
 WHERE zChar.char_num IN
      (SELECT COUNT(zP.char_num) AS charCount
         FROM zPlay  zP, 
              zActor  zAct, 
              zCharacter  zChar
        WHERE zAct.actor_num = zP.actor_num
          AND zChar.char_num = zP.char_num
     GROUP BY zAct.actor_name
 HAVING COUNT(zP.char_num) > 1);
```

FYR,
[techonthenet.com/oracle/alias.php](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/alias.php)